# total distance and time for all waypoints in google maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code for directions from google maps apiv3. This part is working good. If i have waypoints in my trip, at the top of each trip, it is showing the time as well as distance for the trip.
I used a variable totadistance to add the distance from all the legs but, it does nothing. I do not see a alert message when i run the application.
I want to see the total time and distance for all the trips. How can i get that information?

```
  function calcRoute(startaddr, endaddr) {

  var start = document.getElementById(startaddr).value;
  var end = document.getElementById(endaddr).value;
  var waypts = [];
  var waypointstring;
  var waypoint1 = document.getElementById('txtWaypoint').value; 

  waypointstring= waypoint1.split(";");
 //alert("Waypoint Length:" + waypointstring.length)

  for (var i = 0; i < waypointstring.length; i++) {

     waypts.push({location:waypointstring[i], stopover:true});
       }


  var request = {
  origin: start, 
  destination: end,
  waypoints: waypts,
  optimizeWaypoints: true,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING  };
  var totaldistance=0;
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {

  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  var route = response.routes[0];
  var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');

  summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";

  // For each route, display summary information.
  for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
    var routeSegment = i + 1;
    summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment + '</b><br>';
    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
    summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
     totaldistance = totaldistance + route.legs[i].distance.text ;

          }
       alert(totaldistance);
    }


    });

    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a number:

```
totaldistance = totaldistance + route.legs[i].distance.text;
```

This works to give me the total distance in km:

```
 totaldistance = totaldistance + route.legs[i].distance.value;
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_directionsTotalDistance.html)

Comment: geocodezip, changed it to value but no difference. I do not see it. Alert is not coming up.

Comment: If my example works for you, then your code has an error.  Check the javascript console.