# Google map api3, Routing with address search and waypoints

Tags: google-maps-api-3, routes, optional-parameters, jquery-waypoints

i have a question about using the waypoint feature ,**i took the script from the User Geocodezip; very big thanks for that ,and it work well** ,but

i can only route with waypoint ,i would like to have the waypoints as an option,but if the User let this field empty there is no funktion!?
does anyone have an idea???

Comment: What does _your_ code look like?  What have you tried to implement the functionality you are looking for?  What problems did you run into?

Comment: Hi ,and thx for, i tried to put it in jsfiddle .. tried "http://jsfiddle.net/gungott/X8gm4/

Comment: I want build the code for Routing from A to B (only Start to End) AND for the option to insert Waypoints ,now it works only with waypoint(s) not just with A->B,i`m not sure where i can put the parameter for the Waypoints as a Option instead of a musthave ... sry my broken English ..

Comment: You already said that in your question.  What does your code look like? (it should be, at least a [short self contained correct example](http://sscce.org/) of it, posted as part of your question).

Comment: :) sry but i am not very confirm with js  think it has to do with these collumns                                                            var waypts = [];
  var waypointstring;
  var waypoint1 = document.getElementById('txtWaypoint').value;             for (var i = 0; i < waypointstring.length; i++) {    .... i will trie it out, thx for ure attention

Comment: The [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints) does "optional" waypoints.

Comment: Finally i found the Solution :  `  for (var i = 0; i < waypointstring.length; i++) { `
   `var address = waypointstring[i]; 
    if (address !== "") {`

     waypts.push({location:waypointstring[i], stopover:true});
       }
}` thanks for geozipcode for the   for (var i = 0; i < waypointstring.length; i++) {
   var address = waypointstring[i];
    if (address !== "") {

     waypts.push({location:waypointstring[i], stopover:true});
       }
} ` thanks geocodezip for the encouragement and spadework

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    if (waypts.options[i].selected == true) {
```

i insert this line, to Element "waypts" becoming not a mandatory field, but now whole scripts have no funktion.

```
for (var i = 0; i < waypointstring.length; i++) {
if (waypts.options[i].selected == true) {
 waypts.push({location:waypointstring[i], stopover:true});
   }
```

}

Finally found the solution :

```
   var address = waypointstring[i];
if (address !== "") {
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306013/total-distance-and-time-for-all-waypoints-in-google-maps-v3) is the whole source example

Comment: This is not an Answer, this should be part of your Question

Comment: oh ,yes u are right i just want to fill in some code, and take the wrong way ,,but now i tried this and it dont work,: `if(Waypoint[i].value = value`   someone have an idea ?,i tried nearly 100 way for this record