# error retrieving distance and travel time values from a Google API ()

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, maps, bing-maps

im not sure what approach to take next with this, currently I have this below code which calculates the distance in miles between any 2 given locations (using long and lat), however its a straight line, and roads aren't straight... so what I want to do is calculate a distance as google maps would, for example here are some random co-ordinates:

```
lat1:   53.015036674593500
lat2:   -2.244633982337860
long1:   52.363731052413800
long2:  -1.307122733526320
```

and when cast into this code (JavaScript)

```
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
        var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180
        var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2 / 180
        var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1 / 180
        var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2 / 180
        var theta = lon1 - lon2
        var radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180
        var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
        dist = Math.acos(dist)
        dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
        if (unit == "K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
        if (unit == "N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
        return dist
    }

    var dist = distance(lata, longa, latb, longb, unit).toFixed(2);

    window.alert(dist + " miles");
```

the value returned is **59.83** **miles** or there abouts... where if i was to do this in google maps:

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/1+Creswell+Pl,+Cawston,+Rugby+CV22+7GZ,+UK/1+Ironbridge+Dr,+Newcastle+ST5+6ER,+UK/@52.6863234,-2.0253047,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x487747659759ff6f:0x2ae7f451f320ca80!2m2!1d-1.3071227!2d52.3637323!1m5!1m1!1s0x487a67f1ebd6bdaf:0x89c3b0d334683e52!2m2!1d-2.2446339!2d53.0150378

the values range between **77.1 miles** and **76.5 miles**

**The Question**

I have the BELOW function PARTLY working to get the travel time and distance, however it randomly returns "`UNDEFINED`" in the alert box at the bottom, or has this error message

```
"Object doesn't support this action"
```

when using the console.log it returns this message:

```
"google.maps.DistanceMatrixService is not a function"
```

code:

```
 var siteP = postcodearray.indexOf(screen.sitePostcode);
    var StaffP = postcodearray.indexOf(screen.engineerPostcode);

    sitelat = latarray[siteP];
    sitelong = longarray[siteP];
    stafflat = latarray[StaffP];
    stafflong = longarray[StaffP];

    var site = sitelat + ", " + sitelong;
    var staff = stafflat + ", " + stafflong;

    var distance;
    var duration;

    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [staff],
        destinations: [site],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
            distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
            duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
            //var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
            //dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
            //dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
            //dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;

        } else {
            alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
        }
    });

    window.alert(distance); //UNDEFINED
```

Please can someone point out what I have done/am doing wrong here as im so close to getting the 2 values I need

Comment: if you are marking a question down, please leave a comment of why so I can amend the issue

Comment: related question: [get driving distance between two longitude latitude points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131708/get-driving-distance-between-two-longitude-latitude-points)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate distance in meters between two points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775460/calculate-distance-in-meters-between-two-points)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example of using the Bing Maps REST services to calculate a route between to locations in JavaScript here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427607.aspx

I recommend adding the routeAttributes parameter and setting it to routeSummariesOnly. This will make the response really small. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx

Alternatively, if you are using JavaScript and want to load a map, then use the Bing Maps JavaScript control and the directions module: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312802.aspx

You can also find an interactive SDK for the Bing Maps control here: https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#CreateMap1

You will need a Bing Maps key to access the service, but it doesn't have to be tied to a refer. I recommend signing up for a free Bing Maps key here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/bingmaps/mapapis/